# Physical meaning of adding a vector or minus a vector to increase $L^2$ norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Suppose we have two vectors $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with finite dimension.

We use the $L^2$ norm to compare between  $\|a+b\|_2$ and $\|a-b\|_2$.

Trying to get the physical meaning of $\|a+b\|_2 \ge \|a-b\|_2 $ vs $\|a+b\|_2 \le \|a-b\|_2 $.

What can we say about which one is bigger?

Comment: Hint: try squaring both sides of the inequality, writing as dot products, and expanding said dot products. After cancelling like terms, the inequalities simplify substantially to something relatively easy to interpret geometrically.

Comment: so it's testing whether if $a,b$ points to the same direction?

Comment: Not quite. It says something about the angle between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: right if a,b pointing to the similar direction (angle less than 180) it would maps to a+b > a-b, otherwise the opposite

Comment: Replace "180" with "90", then yes, you're right (the angle between any two vectors is less than or equal to 180 degrees).